# Unable to see images in ASP.net web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I made a small web application on ASP.net MVC, everything was working fine until I recently migrated project from my old laptop to new laptop.

The problem is that the images on the webpages are no longer visible. I think problem is somewhere in the configuration. Below is my application's homepage.

[image: My application's home page].

When I inspect elements and see the path of the image, the path is correct. Please let me know where I am doing wrong or there is something else that I am forgetting.

Below is the part of the view which I have shown below:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="media">
        <p class="media-left" style="text-align:center">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/app_icon.png" class="img64by64" alt="" />
        </p>
        <div class="media-body" style="text-align:center">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Download amazing apps</h4>
            Download apps you like & get rewarded.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, when I go to localhost/FreeCube/Content/Images/banner.png on my browser, the image banner.png was displayed on my old laptop, but it is not displayed on new one, do I need to do some configurations in IIS?

Comment: use `@Url.Content()` helper in order to give path to your image tags instead of static paths.

Comment: Please see the update, the code is a part of above displayed image, I was using static paths and it was working fine, why is that not working now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620253/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-vs-redirecttoaction-for-images-in-areas?rq=1

Comment: @MohitVerma this is what I get when I try it: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This answer solved my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solved my issue : stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/…

I needed to enable static content in Turn windows feature on or off. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Nuget Manager and reinstall ASP.NET MVC or update it to a higher version. You can also do this from Package Console with the following command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```